I got a negative number for the partial McFadden's pseudo R^2. Is this possible?
for a logistic regression in R, I'm trying to calculate McFadden's partial R-squared for one predictor variable separately. I used the following code, which I got from this question: How to calculate McFadden's r-squared for just one variable in R?
model1 <- glm(Q22_factor ~ Q24_1 + age, family = "binomial", data = subset_data")
model_age <- glm(Q22_factor ~ age, family = "binomial", data = subset_data)

loss_full <- ModelMetrics::logLoss(
  actual = subset_data$Q22_factor,
  predicted = predict(model1, type = "response")
)

loss_reduced <- ModelMetrics::logLoss(
  actual = subset_data$Q22_factor,
  predicted = predict(model_age, type = "response")
)
(loss_reduced - loss_full)/(loss_reduced)

Using this code on my data, I got a negative outcome (-0.269). Does anyone know if this is possible or did I do anything wrong with my code?

McFadden $R^2$ can be negative. Googling "negative McFadden" gets several cites, including this thread.

Please specify that you are calculating a partial $R^2$. Otherwise, McFadden pseudo $R^2<0$ has a straightforward interpretation.

One place where I could see an issue is that your line data = subset_data") has a stray quotation mark, so your code should fail. Depending on how you are running the code and what you have in memory, you may have defined values differently another time, leading to an unexpectedly small log loss value and the negative $R^2$.
.

Let's dig into the math. The $g$ denotes the logistic regression link function (log-odds), and $g^{-1}$ is its inverse.
Your reduced model is $\hat y = g^{-1}\left(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_{1}\right)$. Your full model is $\hat y = g^{-1}\left(\hat\gamma_0 + \hat\gamma_1x_{1} + \hat\gamma_2x_{2}\right)$. I have changed the Greek letter used to emphasize that the coefficients can be different in the two models.
The $\hat\beta_i$ are calculated by minimizing the log loss discussed in my answer to your earlier question, denoted $L$.
$$
\hat\beta = \underset{\beta\in\mathbb R^2}{\arg\min}\left\{
L(y, g^{-1}\left(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1}\right))
\right\}
$$
The $\hat\gamma_i$ are calculated similarly.
$$
\hat\gamma = \underset{\gamma\in\mathbb R^3}{\arg\min}\left\{
L(y, g^{-1}\left(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1x_{1} + \gamma_2x_{2}\right))
\right\}
$$
Claim: In-sample, that is, on the data used to fit the models (which should be the same), $L(y, g^{-1}\left(\hat\gamma_0 + \hat\gamma_1x_{1} + \hat\gamma_2x_{2}\right)) \le L(y, g^{-1}\left(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_{1}\right)$.
That is, the in-sample loss for the complex model is no larger than that of the simple model nested within it.
Proof
That "nested within it" line is key.
$g^{-1}\left(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_{1}\right) = g^{-1}\left(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_{1} + 0x_{2}\right)$
$
\hat\gamma = \left(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1, 0\right)
$ is a possible solution for $\hat\gamma$, so whatever minimizes the loss must give a loss as least as small as the loss $L\left(
y, g^{-1}\left(
\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_1 + 0x_2
\right)
\right) = L\left(y, g^{-1}\left(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_{1}\right)\right)$.
$\square$ (End of proof)
The takeaway is that the loss for the complex model cannot be any higher than the loss of the simple model nested within it. You are observing this behavior, leaving a few options.

The code I wrote in the other answer is incorrect.

I think it is correct.

The ModelMetrics::logLoss function miscalculates the log loss.

I think that function is correct, but feel free to try a function from another package.

Your logistic regressions are not estimated correctly.

The solver in glm is pretty good.

The predictions are not correct.

I think they are.

There is a bug somewhere in your code causing you to calculate a loss_full value higher than loss_reduced.

This is my suspicion.
I pointed out in a comment that model1 <- glm(Q22_factor ~ Q24_1 + age, family = "binomial", data = subset_data") in your code has a stray quotation mark that will cause code to fail. Depending on how you run your code and what you have in memory (perhaps a different data set stored as subset_data), you might wind up with incorrect values of loss_full and/or loss_reduced. Other bugs are possible, too.

Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer! I think you're right. The stray quotation is not the problem (I already ran it without it) but there is probably some other mistake.  What I also noticed is that the log-reduced and the log-full both have negative numbers. The loss-full is -0.1 and the loss-reduced is -0.079. So I think a mistake caused both of them to be wrong. The example code you gave worked well on my computer, I got the same result as you.

@Geke The ModelMetrics function returns a negative value? I wonder if there is a known bug leading to the function sometimes giving negative values. Perhaps try a different package.

@Geke Any luck?
